# Detect if an Android app was downloaded from Google Play vs Amazon vs Other

Tags: android, google-play, amazon-appstore

I know this is probably a longshot, but is there any way to detect programatically whether an app was hosted on the Amazon apps store vs on Google Play? I would like to link to the app store the app was downloaded from, and I'd rather not have two different APKs with just this difference if it can be avoided.

Comment: do apps loaded from amazon get their updates from there...........?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of just recently, the Amazon Appstore returns sane values for `PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()`

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
String installerPackageName = pm.getInstallerPackageName(context.getPackageName());

if ("com.android.vending".equals(installerPackageName)) {
    //do google things
} else if ("com.amazon.venezia".equals(installerPackageName)) {
    //do amazon things
}
```

See here:
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=680

Examples for rate this app links:

**Google Play-**

> market://details?id=PACKAGANAME

**Amazon Store**

> http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=PACKAGENAME

or

> amzn://apps/android?p=com.amazon.mp3

Comment: Hi @AlfieHanssen. I still need to verify this.

Comment: Note that getInstallerPackageName() may return null if the app was installed using ADB

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use different version codes or names between Amazon and Google Play. Then you can use [PackageManager.getPackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to retrieve those values and choose the app store link appropriately from there.

Example: suffix all of your Amazon version names with '.65' i.e., 1.0.65. Then use

```
public boolean isAmazon(Context context) {
    String versionName = "";
    try {
        versionName = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // Can't find itself...
    }
    return versionName.endsWith(".65");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is one way to do it, but unfortunately it's a compile-time change that doesn't solve the specific case. I could just as easily add a meta-data tag to my manifest, which is probably cleaner in the long run, as versions can remain identical for both packages.

Comment: It's better to use PackageName instead of VersionName because it is weird to add a letter to a version (easier to change the bundle name).

Comment: Also Amazon does not accept version name different from x.x.x.x.x where x is only integers. Read it here: [Link](https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/submitting-your-app/tech-docs/submitting-your-app)